# Find the value $V_k$ as a function of $Z_1, \dots , Z_k$.

Tags: calculus

Consider a yearly investment of 1,000 dollars in long positions in a portfolio of stocks
and a risk-free one-year zero coupon bond over a 30-year period. The yearly returns on
the portfolio of stocks year $k$ is modeled as $R_k = e^{μ+σZ_k}$ , where $Z_k$ is standard normally distributed. The yearly returns are assumed to be independent. The yearly return on the risk-free bond is assumed to be $e^{0.01}$. Each year, after the investment of 1,000 dollars has been added, the entire portfolio is rebalanced such that the fraction of the total portfolio value invested in the stocks at the beginning of year k is $\alpha_k$, where $\alpha_k \in (0,1)$.

Find the value $V_k$ as a function of $Z_1, \dots , Z_k$.

Formulating the problem recursively is not hard, yielding

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
V_{k+1} &= (V_k + 1000)(\alpha_k \cdot R_{k+1} + (1- \alpha_k) \cdot e^r) \\
V_0 &= 1000.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

However, it is not sufficient, as I need $V_k = f(Z_1,\dots,Z_k)$. Writing out the first terms yields

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
V_1 &= (V_0+1000)(\alpha_0R_{1}+(1-\alpha_0)e^r) \\
V_2 &= (V_1 + 1000)(\alpha_1R_{2}+(1-\alpha_1)e^r) \\
&= [(V_0+1000)(\alpha_0R_{1}+(1-\alpha_0)e^r)+1000] (\alpha_1R_{2}+(1-\alpha_1)e^r) \\
V_3 &= \big[[(V_0+1000)(\alpha_0R_{1}+(1-\alpha_0)e^r)+1000] (\alpha_1R_{2}+(1-\alpha_1)e^r) + 1000 \big] (\alpha_2 R_{3}+(1-\alpha_2)e^r)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Giving chatGPT the the sequence, it suggested that

$$V_n = V_0 \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (\alpha_i R_{i+1} + (1-\alpha_i) e^r) + 1000 \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \prod_{j=i}^{n-1} (\alpha_j R_{j+1} + (1-\alpha_j) e^r) \right)
$$

Although I have no clue how it got there or if it's correct. Am I missing something?